Let $g(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} {\left((x+1)^{r+1} - x^{r+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}}$. Find $\lim_{x\to \infty}{\frac{g(x)}{x}}$
Task:
The function $g(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} {\left((x+1)^{r+1} - x^{r+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}}$ is defined for any positive real $x$. Calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{g(x)}{x}}$.
My attempt:
My idea was based on taking the derivative and reducing it to the limit of the form $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e}$. So, let's set $f(x) = x^{r+1}$. $f'(x) = (1+r)x^r$. According to definition of derivative $f'(x) = (x+1)^{r+1} - x^{r+1}$.
Summarizing $g(x) = x\lim_{r\to 0}{\left(1+r\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}} = ex;$
$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{g(x)}{x}} = e$.
Is my rationale correct?

Please don't repost

That "attempt" is indeed the first part of my (now deleted) answer to your earlier question.
